# Processing pairs of events from a database

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new to sql, and was wondering if there was a simple way to query a database for pairs of entries. Specifically, In this database table, there are a bunch of entries that describe various events. A particular event will first appear (in one row) as acknowledged, and the next entry for the same event, are marked as processed. I want to know if there's an elegant way to get each such pair of entries, perform some calculations on them, and then move onto the next pair until there are no more entries.

Comment: Do you have some sort of key that ties the two events together.  Many SQL systems don't always return records in physical order- so the concept of "next" may be tricky.

Comment: Each entry has a name field. Obviously, two events are the same event if they have the same name. Also, they have a field called status which stores whether the events was ACKD (acknowledged) or PROC (processed). Also, if an entry says it was acknowledged, the next entry with the same name must have the status processed. Also, entries are recorded chronologically, and have a time field with a time for when they occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a join like this:

```
select *
from events a
     events p
     on a.eventid = p.eventid and
        a.status = 'acknowledged' and
        p.status = processed;
```

This will bring back the pairs of rows.  Of course, this is subject to lots of conditions, but it is a general way to approach what you are asking for.

Comment: These are in the same table, so I'm assuming it might look something like

Answer (score 0):

W/o any schema one can only speak in generalities, but you could do a join to get appropriate pairs of rows.